# Is it possible to create a IOS app that can download plugins and extension later?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-app-extension, ios-app-group

we have a ios app that provides the platform for many similar games. When you install this app. This app already contains binaries of x number of games.

Now we are having size issue. So just wanted to know is it possible to create a ios app that can get installed and after that as per user selection can download the games binaries separately and then run.  Like a app that can download games as plugins or extensions.

I work on game side part so i dont know anything about ios apps. but so far  my understanding is  -> when you create the ios executable then while compiling you should have all the code present (app + all the games it will run).

Comment: Are you sure the size issue is from the code? Seems more likely to me you'd get a size issue from images, video, and audio, all of which could be downloaded later.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to download a native executable and run it -- that is not a capability provided by app extensions.

One loophole you might consider: it is perfectly permissible to download and run javascript, or anything else that runs in a `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`, which are both sandboxed from your iOS App's process, and have access to OpenGLES 2.0 in the form of WebGL. There are also apps which have been accepted in the App Store which can run code in interpreted languages like Python.